# creating a new dataframe based off if a particular value matches a value in a list

Tags: python, pandas, merge, filtering, dataframe

What I have is data in a pandas dataframe.  There is one column that contains an customer_id.  These are not unique ids.  I have a list of selected customer ids (there are no repeating values in the list).  What I want to do is create a new dataframe based on the ids in the list.  I want all rows for each id in the list.  All the data has been read in as str.
Here is my code:

```
for i in range(len(df_ALL)):
if df_ALL.loc[i,"Customer_ID"] in ID_list:
    df_Sub = df_Sub.append(df_ALL.iloc[i,:])
```

When I run this on simple small files it runs.  However when I run it on the real data it returns a "KeyError: 'the label [2666] is not in the [index]'"  I have only be using python/pandas for about 4-5 months, I tried to research a solution to this problem but I couldn't find something that I understood.  If there is a better method to accomplish my goal I am open to learning it.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you post sample data and code that reproduces your error, it sounds like what you are trying to is create a new df of all the customers in your list correct? How about `df[df['Customer_ID'].isin(ID_list)]` I believe should work

Comment: @EdChum You are correct! This is exactly what I want to do.  I used the `isin` as you suggested and it worked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you've not posted any data or code I will demonstrate how the following should work for you. You can pass a list to [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html#pandas.Series.isin) which will return a boolean index which you can use to filter your df, there is no need to loop over and append the rows of interest. It's probably failing for you (I'm guessing as I don't have your data) because you've either gone off the end or your index doesn't contain that specific label value.

```
In [147]:

customer_list=['Microsoft', 'Google', 'Facebook']
df = pd.DataFrame({'Customer':['Microsoft', 'Microsoft', 'Google', 'Facebook','Google', 'Facebook', 'Apple','Apple'], 'data':np.random.randn(8)})
df
Out[147]:
    Customer      data
0  Microsoft  0.669051
1  Microsoft  0.392646
2     Google  1.534285
3   Facebook -1.204585
4     Google  1.050301
5   Facebook  0.492487
6      Apple  1.471614
7      Apple  0.762598
In [148]:

df['Customer'].isin(customer_list)
Out[148]:
0     True
1     True
2     True
3     True
4     True
5     True
6    False
7    False
Name: Customer, dtype: bool
In [149]:

df[df['Customer'].isin(customer_list)]
Out[149]:
    Customer      data
0  Microsoft  0.669051
1  Microsoft  0.392646
2     Google  1.534285
3   Facebook -1.204585
4     Google  1.050301
5   Facebook  0.492487
```

Comment: Would it be more efficient to create a second pandas dataframe from the "customer_list" list and then perform a SQL type merge?

Comment: @Knop a dict or df would be fine for this purpose